# Enabling the data from second dropdown when it selected in the first dropdown with jQuery

Tags: java, html, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How can I write a jQuery function that enables the value from second dropdown only if a value is selected on the first dropdown?

As I selected Shiva in first drop down it should be disabled from 2nd drop down.

fist drop down value must not be equal to 2nd dropdown.

```
<select class="form-control" id="select2">
   <option value="1556456">Shiva</option>
   <option value="34234">Disha</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="select3">
    <option value="1556456">Shiva</option>
    <option value="34234">Disha</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean. Let me know. You can use a .find and .filter on it.

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $('option').prop('disabled', false);
    $('select').each(function() {
        var val = this.value;
        $('select').not(this).find('option').filter(function() {
            return this.value === val;
        }).prop('disabled', true);
    });
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<select class="form-control" id="select2">
   <option value="1556456">Shiva</option>
   <option value="34234">Disha</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="select2">
    <option value="1556456">Shiva</option>
    <option value="34234">Disha</option>
</select>

</form>
```